# Laravel - Use language permanently after login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware, laravel-localization

I have an application in laravel and now I need to put this in several languages.

In user table I add a column `lang` that tells me the default language for each user.
So after login I create a `session` variable to store this value:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
  session(['locale' => $user->lang]);
}
```

Next I create and register a `middleware` to set the language for each route:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  if(session()->has('locale'))
  {
    app()->setLocale(session('locale'));
  }
  else
  {
    app()->setLocale(config('app.locale'));
  }

  return $next($request);
}
```

If I echo the session it gives me the correct lang based on logged user.

But this doesn't work, puts always the default language set in laravel config file.

How can I solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Use parentheses when you write your `if` statements and mistakes like this will not happen anymore.

Comment: And you might want to introduce an `else` before you set the default language...

Comment: I already tried this but doesn't work @Namoshek

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the locale:

```
// Check if session has locale
if(session()->has('locale'))
    // set session locale 
    app()->setLocale(session('locale'));

// this is outside the condition block
// so it will run everytime
app()->setLocale(config('app.locale'));
```

You could use curly brackets to avoid this, like so:

```
if(session()->has('locale')) {
    app()->setLocale(session('locale'));
} else {
    app()->setLocale(config('app.locale'));    
}
```

Or if you dont like curly brackets, initiate with the default locale and then change it based on if its available in the sessions, like so:

```
app()->setLocale(config('app.locale')); 
if(session()->has('locale'))
    app()->setLocale(session('locale'));
```

Comment: You are correct! I already change the code but doesn't work yet. @AngadDubey

Comment: Have you verified that `session('locale')` contains the right value and that a directory with translations exists within the `resources.lang` folder which has the same name as the session value?

Comment: I detect the problem! I'm doing wrong the middleware registry! Sorry and Thank you @Namoshek

Comment: I detect the problem! I'm doing wrong the middleware registry! Sorry and Thank you @AngadDubey

Answer (score 0):

I did it in the following way:

Here is my middleware (setLocale):

```
class SetLocale
{

    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if( isset(auth()->user()->language) && auth()->user()->language ) {
            App::setLocale('fa');
        }else{
            App::setLocale('en');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

---

LanguageController:

public function changeLanguage(int $lang_code): RedirectResponse
{

```
App::setLocale($lang_code);

$user = auth()->user();
$user->language = $lang_code;
$user->save();

return redirect()->back();
```

}

---

nav.blade.php (you will need bootstrap 4 for this):

```
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="languageMenuBtn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                {{ isset(auth()->user()->language) && !auth()->user()->language ? 'Persian': 'English' }}
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="languageMenuBtn">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ isset(auth()->user()->language) && !auth()->user()->language ? route('change_language', 1) : route('change_language', 0) }}">
                    {{ isset(auth()->user()->language) && !auth()->user()->language ?  'English' : 'Persian' }}
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

---

Route (web.php):

```
Route::get('change_language/{lang}', [App\Http\Controllers\LanguageController::class, 'changeLanguage'])->name('change_language');
```